# Disable PageView scrolling in Card widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Imagine, that you have two pages - pages A and B.

Of course, you can switch between pages by clicking on the tab bar or swipe (left to right or right to left).

On page A, there are multiple `Card` widgets, one of them contains `charts.TimeSeriesChart`.

Chart contains behaviour: `charts.SlidingViewport(), charts.PanAndZoomBehavior(),` nevertheless it doesn't work.
When I put `physics:NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),` into `PageView`, charts getting scrollable feature.

**Question:**
I would like to allow swipe between tabs, but how to disable swipe between tabs only in this `Card` widget (with chart), and make sliding working in Chart?

I'm using this package: https://pub.dev/packages/charts_flutter

Comment: Please upload the code you are using

Comment: https://github.com/google/charts/issues/237 - you could check this, it is similar issue

Comment: Please share a code snippet, also you could wrap the widget with an AbsorbPoinet, but without the actual code I can't say if it fits your use case